# iOS 9 UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification callback not called

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplication, ios9

In iOS 9 the following code for detecting a notification does not fire the selector method. In previous versions (e.g. 8.4) it's running fine. Does anyone know why?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];

- (void)yourMethod {NSLog(@"aaaaaaa");}
```

Comment: As iOS 9 is in beta, you might get a better response on Apple's developer forums.

Answer (score 6):

This link as below maybe help your problem.

[Foundation Release Notes for OS X v10.11](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter)

Use "**addObserverForName**" instead of "addObserver".

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification * Nonnull note) {
                                                      [self yourMethod];
                                                  }];
```

It will be work.

Comment: If you want to use `addObserver:`, your app must have some UI contents that using `NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 3):

I hade the same problem and for me it worked to move the addObserver code to awakeFromNib. Another solution could be to add a delay to the addObserver as in the example below:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While doing some tests, I noted that the notification is actually triggered, albeit not at launch time (or at least too early to be caught by your observer) (**on the simulator only**).

Try pulling the notification center down and up or the control center up and down, and you'll see your method will actually be called.

I'd suggest maybe calling your method manually on iOS 9, when your app starts?

**On a real device, the method is called just as on iOS 8.**

**Edit**: after further investigation, it seems the notification is actually not triggered every time on devices :/

Answer (score 0):

I've also bumped into this problem and adding the observer with a delay didn't solve it in my case. Managed to get rid of it by calling the method directly in AppDelegate and from the main queue, without a delay.

Swift:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

        yourMethod()
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue only on real devices running iOS 9.0 and up.

I ended up defining my own notification:
(this define should be globally available, `constants.h` or alike)

```
#define myAppBecameActiveNotif @"Tito, your app is active"
```

Then, in your AppDelegate implementation (AppDelegate.m most of the cases) you implement `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:myAppBecameActiveNotif
                                                            object:nil];
    });
}
```

(Just delay the dispatch of your notification a bit, to let your components come to life)

Now, in the class you'd like to be notified the app became active you do

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(whatToDoWhenAppActive:)
                                                 name:myAppBecameActiveNotif
                                               object:nil];
```

Working good now. You'll see you cannot feel this 500ms delay...

Answer (score -1):

I do notification register like that.

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethod:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Write Method like that.

```
- (void)yourMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
     NSLog(@"aaaaaaa");
  }
```

Also you need to NSLog in AppDelegate.m and see log in console.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
      NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
 }
```

Comment: This does nothing more than restate the problem

Comment: You can say kind of. But actually told him/her a way how to investigate.